# How to send post request to tt-rss api using retrofit

Tags: android, curl, retrofit

I have read a lot about Retrofit but really have dough on how to implement post request to tt-rss api using retrofit.

in the tt-rss api documentations, it says that to test login request using curl, it should be something like this:

```
$ curl -d '{"op":"login","user":"you","password":"xxx"}' http://example.dom/tt-rss/api/
```

I have used the following call but gives me "NOT_LOGGED_IN"error message

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/login")
Observable<login> doLogin(@Field("user") String user,@Field("password") String password);
```

i don't know what is the wrong with this call..

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Body` annotation on parameter to get it transferred as JSON. You can pass complex object or Map

Here is example in Kotlin (easy to do the same in pure Java)

```
data class LoginRequest(val login : String, val password : String, val op : String = "login")

trait LoginService {

    POST("/api/login")
    fun doLogin(Body login : LoginRequest) : Obervable<login>

    POST("/api/login")
    fun doLogin2(Body login : Map<String, String) : Observable<login>
}
```